# oci_connect(): ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred Ubuntu18.04 CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, linux, oracle, codeigniter

Hola amigos tengo un problema ya hice todo para conectar mi aplicacion a oracle no logro hacer que funcione, estoy seguro que funciona en windows 10 con XAMMP pero no logro hacerlo funcionar en ubuntu 18.04 ya instale OCI8, ya configure todo lo que encontre en internet y no logre hacerlo funcionar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La conexion de mi base de datos hacia oracle es esta.

```
$tnsname ='(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ip_del_servidor)(PORT=1521)))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=puvidb)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))';


$db['oruvi'] = array(

    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => $tnsname,
    'username' => 'my_user',
    'password' => 'my_pass',
    'database' => 'puvidb',
    'dbdriver' => 'oci8',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'WE8ISO8859P1',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Igual tengo otra conexion en otro archivo donde este se encarga de todos los procesos de consultas insert y update que hace mi aplicación.

```
 public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
      echo "<h1>On the constructor</h1><br>";
      $this->db_oracle = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ip_del_servidor)(PORT=1521)))
      (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=puvidb)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))';
      $this->conexion = oci_connect("my_user", "my_password", $this->db_oracle,"AL32UTF8");
      if (!$this->conexion) {
         $m = oci_error();
         trigger_error(htmlentities($m['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
     }
   }
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que la BD y mi aplicación estan en diferentes servidores, los dos son linux(ubuntu18.04)

**El error que me da es este:** Tener en cuenta que los errores que me indican las lineas son por que no se han podido hacer las respectivas consultas a la BD por el problema de la conexion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, espero a nadie le ocurre, el error no esta en el codigo al aprecer mi codigo era correcto. Pero hay un detalle y es que mi aplicacion esta en un servidor Linux(Ubuntu18.04) y la BD esta en otro servidor linux(Ubuntu18.04) osea estan separados; ahora yo estaba intentado conectarme por medio de la ip=(ip_publica) lo que ocurria es que el sevidor al tener que usar la ip publica pues no podia conectarse ya que estos dos servidores estan conectados localmente la solucion a esto es conectarme por medio de la ip=(ip_privada).

Ahora recomiendo para que prueben Instalen en sus servidores Ubuntu SQLPLus para que puedan conectarse a BD oracle y usen este comando. sqlplus Usuario/Contraseña_Del_Usuario@Aqui_va_la_ip_de_la_BD:1521/Aqui_va_EL_SID Ejemplo: sqlplus system/contraseña@localhost:1521/orcl Es importante que prueben todas las ip posibles si ven que nos les conecta. Final de la solución:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]